# How to provide any additional details for certification review when submitting an extension to Microsoft Edge Add-ons website?

Tags: microsoft-edge, browser-extension, microsoft-edge-extension, browser-addons, microsoft-edge-chromium

I have been working on submitting an extension to the Microsoft Edge Add-ons store. I wanted to provide details on the steps to test my extension and the functionality. But I am unable to find an option to add these details in my submission. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

When submitting your extension, use the **Notes for certification page** to provide additional information to the certification testers. The additional information helps ensure that your extension is tested correctly. If your extension isn't fully tested, it may fail certification.

**Ensure you include the following information, as necessary.**

- User names and passwords for test accounts.
- Steps to access hidden or
  locked features.
- Expected differences in functionality based on
  region or other user settings.
- If your submission is an update to an
  existing extension, include information about the changes made to the
  extension.
- Any other additional information that testers must understand
  about your submission.

After providing the information, choose **Publish** to submit your extension to the Microsoft Edge Add-ons store.

Your submission proceeds to the certification step. The certification process may take up to **seven business days** after your submission.

When your submission passes certification, your extension is published in the Microsoft Edge Add-ons store. The status of your extension in the Partner Center dashboard changes to **In the Store**.